# Change table topic name in Goka

Tags: go, apache-kafka

Hi I am using goka to do stream processing in go.

Is it possible to change the table topic name when defining a group ?

```
g := goka.DefineGroup(goka.Group("mygroup"),
    goka.Input(goka.Stream(*userProcessTopic), UserOpMsgCodec{}, msgCb),
    // here replace topic "mygroup-table" by "mygroup.data" for instance        
    goka.Persist(MyCodec{}), 
)
```

something like

```
    goka.PersistTo(MyCodec{}, "mytableName")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current version 0.1.0 that is not possible. All group tables are named as the group name suffixed with "-table". In your example, the group table is "mygroup-table".

You can open an issue at https://github.com/lovoo/goka/issues if you need such a feature.